# Calling GSL functions via NativeCall in Raku throws error

Tags: docker, lapack, gsl, raku, nativecall

### Problem

I am trying to call [cumulative distribution function of chisq function](https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/doc/html/randist.html#c.gsl_cdf_chisq_P) in [GSL](https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/doc/html/) from raku.

This is my raku script `chisq.raku`

```
#Calling gsl_cdf_chisq-P function in GSL from raku

use NativeCall;

sub gsl_cdf_chisq_P(num64, num64) returns num64 is native('gsl') { * };
sub gsl_cdf_chisq_Q(num64, num64) returns num64 is native('gsl') { * };


sub pchisq($q, $df, $lower-tail = True) {
  my $a = $q.Num;
  my $b = $df.Num;
  if $lower-tail == True {
    return gsl_cdf_chisq_P($a, $b)
  } else {
    return gsl_cdf_chisq_Q($a, $b)
  }
  }

say pchisq(3,4);
```

While executing this script, I get following error:

```
Cannot locate native library '(null)': /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgsl.so: undefined symbol: cblas_ctrmv
  in method setup at /usr/share/perl6/core/sources/947BDAB9F96E0E5FCCB383124F923A6BF6F8D76B (NativeCall) line 286
  in block gsl_cdf_chisq_P at /usr/share/perl6/core/sources/947BDAB9F96E0E5FCCB383124F923A6BF6F8D76B (NativeCall) line 578
  in sub pchisq at chisq.raku line 13
  in block <unit> at chisq.raku line 19
```

From reading the documentation on [NativeCall](https://docs.perl6.org/language/nativecall), I am including the shared library `libgsl.so`.

Googling showed `cblas_ctrmv` was possibly (not sure) related with [lapack](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/d3/d21/cblas__ctrmv_8c_a5eb1d4518355a4d655bb5ff7e8a6f2fd.html).

So I searched for `liblapack.so` which was indeed present inside `/usr/lib`.
`echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH` showed

```
/usr/local/lib/R/lib::/lib:/usr/local/lib:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/server
```

To see if I can fix it, I added `/usr/lib` to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` with command `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/lib` and tried to run the script again.

Still not working, same error message.

### Environment:

I am running code in [docker container inside rstudio](https://hub.docker.com/r/sumankhanal/rakurstudio).

Raku version 2019.11

It has `gsl-dev` files and `gsl` library.
The container has shared library `libgsl.so` inside `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/`.
Other shared libraries inside this folder are
[image]

**Is there a way to make it work?**

Comment: If I understand this correctly, this is a shared library that is called from another shared library, is that correct? My hunch here is that the second, shared, library is not loaded. What I would do is to declare the `cblas_ctrmv` with its corresponding library within the script, so that its library is registered and thus it can be called.

Comment: Also note that Fernando Santagata is working on a GSL module, I believe.

Comment: I tested the code on Ubuntu 19.10, and it worked (I already had installed gsl library) immediately. The output was: 0.4421745996289249.

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49036300/nativecall-loading-a-library-symbol-i-dont-call  Also see rakudo enhancement request: https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/issues/1584

Comment: Yes, I'm working on a libgsl interface module.
561 functions converted so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the base image of `rocker/rstudio` is updated to `debian:buster`.

After installation of `libgsl23`, the problem is resolved.

It works now !!

Answer (score 3):

I verified that the version of libgsl and libgslcblas shipped with Ubuntu 18.04 produce the kind of error you found.
I installed the Debian Buster version of both libraries (even if it's not good practice) and that miraculously cured the problem.